# Get value of display:column property JSP page in JS

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I don't know how to get the value of a display:column in a JSP page to check in a JS function.

JSP Page:

```
<display:table>
...

<display:column property="surnameName" title="Surname, Name" />
<display:column property="type" title="Type"/>
....
</display:table>
```

JS function:

```
function next2(){
...
var type = $('.type').val(); //Obtain an undefined value
...
if (documents.length > 1 && (type=='Mail Addresss' || type=='Ordinary')) {

        alert("You must select at least a PDF for Mail Addresss or Ordinary type for the stakeholder");

        return false;

    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function next2() {
var types = []; 


$('.your-table-selector').find('tr').each(function() {
    
    var type = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().trim(); // Assuming type is in the second column (index 1)

    
    types.push(type);
});

if (types.length > 1 && (types.includes('Mail Addresss') || types.includes('Ordinary'))) {
    alert("You must select at least a PDF for Mail Addresss or Ordinary type for the stakeholder");
    return false;
}}
```

Replace '.your-table-selector' with the appropriate selector for your table. This code assumes that the type values are displayed in the second column of your table. Adjust the index in td:eq() if the column position is different.

This JavaScript function will extract all the type values from the displayed table rows and perform the necessary validation based on the conditions you've specified.

Comment: Hi, @LalitKumar Many thanks for your solution. But in case of id="resultTable" in display:table, how does it code in JS, please? Blessings! :)